# Sticky top-bar and side-bar on a CSS daily planning layout

Tags: css, grid

I'm trying to get a multi-ressource planning application running with Symfony, so I'm working on a CSS layout to display the daily planning.

Here is a schema of what I'm trying to achieve, with pure CSS if possible :

[Daily planning layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHYcm.png)

I'd like Area 1 & 2 to be sticky regarding the left and top side of their container, in order to allow the user to browse Area 3 (where the bookings will be displayed) while keeping the labels in view (especially on mobile).

What I've tried is here in this code snippet (the planning container dimension are purposely small in order to trigger the undesirable behavior, but don't hesitate to adjust it regarding to your screen):

```css
.planning-container {
  background-color: #80bdff;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 80vh;
  width: 40vw;
}

.line {
  display: flex;
}

.line .empty-cell {
  background-color: #d2d2d2;
  min-width: 20px;
  max-width: 20px;
  min-height: 45px;
  max-height: 45px;
  margin: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
}

.line .cell-offset {
  min-width: 10px;
}

.line .title-cell {
  background-color: #22c645;
  min-width: 120px;
  max-width: 120px;
  min-height: 45px;
  max-height: 45px;
  margin: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
}

.line .title-cell--first {
  min-height: 20px;
  max-height: 20px;
}

.line--first {
  background-color: #5eb5e0;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.line--first .hour-cell {
  background-color: #d39e00;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 700;
  min-width: 20px;
  max-width: 20px;
  min-height: 20px;
  max-height: 20px;
  margin: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="planning-container">
    <div class="line line--first">
        <div class="title-cell title-cell--first"></div>
        <div class="hour-cell">
            0h
        </div>
        <div class="hour-cell">
        </div>
        <div class="hour-cell">
        </div>
        <div class="hour-cell">
        </div>
        <div class="hour-cell">
            1h
        </div>
        <div class="hour-cell">
        </div>
        <div class="hour-cell">
        </div>
        <div class="hour-cell">
        </div>
        <div class="hour-cell">
            2h
        </div>
        <div class="hour-cell">
        </div>
        <div class="hour-cell">
        </div>
        <div class="hour-cell">
        </div>
        <div class="hour-cell">
            3h
        </div>
        <div class="hour-cell">
        </div>
        <div class="hour-cell">
        </div>
        <div class="hour-cell">
        </div>
        <div class="hour-cell">
            4h
        </div>
        <div class="hour-cell">
        </div>
        <div class="hour-cell">
        </div>
        <div class="hour-cell">
        </div>
        <div class="hour-cell">
            5h
        </div>
        <div class="hour-cell">
        </div>
        <div class="hour-cell">
        </div>
        <div class="hour-cell">
        </div>
        <div class="hour-cell">
            6h
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="line">
        <div class="title-cell">
            Title cell
        </div>
        <div class="cell-offset"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="line">
        <div class="title-cell">
            Title cell
        </div>
        <div class="cell-offset"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="line">
        <div class="title-cell">
            Title cell
        </div>
        <div class="cell-offset"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="line">
        <div class="title-cell">
            Title cell
        </div>
        <div class="cell-offset"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="line">
        <div class="title-cell">
            Title cell
        </div>
        <div class="cell-offset"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="line">
        <div class="title-cell">
            Title cell
        </div>
        <div class="cell-offset"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="line">
        <div class="title-cell">
            Title cell
        </div>
        <div class="cell-offset"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="line">
        <div class="title-cell">
            Title cell
        </div>
        <div class="cell-offset"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="line">
        <div class="title-cell">
            Title cell
        </div>
        <div class="cell-offset"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="line">
        <div class="title-cell">
            Title cell
        </div>
        <div class="cell-offset"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="line">
        <div class="title-cell">
            Title cell
        </div>
        <div class="cell-offset"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
        <div class="empty-cell"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

See how the "Title" cells disappear ? I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52750172/left-side-sticky-element-disappears-when-scrolling-to-the-right) that it's an overflow issue, and the proposed solution is to make an inline-grid layout inside the container. While the solution works fine on a computer screen, it has a strange behavior on mobile, and the "sticky labels" requirement is not met.

Is there a simple way to achieve this with pure CSS ?

Thank you in advance,

Samy

Comment: Hello, I would highly recommend to add the code snippet you have worked on so far, and narrow the question down more. Your current question might be too broad to answer at this point.

Comment: Absolutely, I'll edit my post